# How to target multiple versions of Windows

Tags: c, windows

I am using visual studio 2017 and Windows 7 (sp1). I compiled a c program on my computer. But, On my friend's computer, it's not running. I don't want to share my source code. My friend uses windows 10. How can I compile my program to run on both computers. 
Thank you!

Comment: What happens when you run it on your friend's computer?

Comment: Define "it's not running."  Does the program crash?  Do you get any error messages?

Comment: If you're compiling in Debug mode, it won't run without the appropriate windows sdk installed. If you're compiling in Release mode, it won't run without the appropriate vcredist installed on the target machine

Comment: You may find some hints here: [Deploying Native Desktop Applications (Visual C++)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/ide/deploying-native-desktop-applications-visual-cpp?view=vs-2017)

Answer (score 4):

To make a compiled deliverable that works on other machines in Visual Studio, what you need to do is:

- Compile in Release mode (it is Debug by default)
- Ship the appropriate Visual C++ Redistributable package with your executable
- Ensure that the target architecture (x86, x64, ARM, or Itanium) is appropriate for your particular deliverable

Creating a setup wizard makes a lot of this easier.

Also note that [Windows SmartScreen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SmartScreen#Windows) will by default not allow computers to run foreign, un-digitally signed programs acquired from the Internet.